# How to prevent a component to load again on query parameter change in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

```
this.router.navigate(['CurrentComponent', {id: this._id, param1: value}]);
```

Above code updates the query parameters of the present url. And after the url is changed, the component loads again.
How to prevent the reload of component and only update the query parameters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a method `routerCanReuse` to your component and return `true`

```
routerCanReuse(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) { return true; }
```

See also [CanReuse](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanReuse-interface.html)